# Bott-type projections in $C^*$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, noncommutative-geometry

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $a\in A$. If $aa^*+1$ is invertible in $A$ then the element
$$\beta(a)=(aa^*+I)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc}aa^* & a \\a^* & I\end{array}\right)$$
is an idempotent. 
The formula is similar to the one defining the Bott projection in the classical case.

I wanted to know what does the above $\beta$ mean for the $K$-theory of $A$? Does it have any significance similar to the classical Bott projection?

Comment: Probably nothing. It is unitarily conjugate to the projection $1 \oplus 0$ (as is evident by looking at the row $(a, 1)$, and for its complement), and of course there is a path of projections to the standard one from it.

Comment: How about when viewed as a function of $a$?